# Rpi3 is the hardware watchdog enabled by default

Tags: pi-3, device-tree, watchdog

I have RaspberryPI's 3 (running both Jessie and Stretch) and tested on both

In order to enable the watchdog timer, In many posts I saw that add in the /boot/config.txt a line with:

```
dtparam=watchdog=on
```

this would enable the watchdog in the device tree.

However, either I add the line or I don't add it, in the dmesg I see

```
bcm2835-wdt 3f100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
```

The line does not appear in the dmesg only when I add:

```
dtparam=watchdog=off
```

So my **question** is
Is the watchdog timer enabled by default?

Relative posts

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=147501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed in Pi3 using stretch (and even jessie) the hardware watchdog is enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

In (soon to be unsupported) Jessie there is a known bug in the systemd script - See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/68332/8697

This is fixed in Stretch.

I don't know how (or why) you got the ancient Wheezy running on a Pi3. My memory for ancient history is poor, but I didn't think Wheezy had support for Device Tree.

Comment: Sorry, I made an mistake, I have jessie and stretch running. However, I am not talking about the watchdog daemon but about the hardware configuration of the watchdog 

As for the bug in Jessie, I am aware of it as it is also mentioned in the link I posted.