# Raspberry Pi not booting after power outage

Tags: boot-issues

My apartment experiences frequent power outages. After a power outage there is an about 50% chance of the pi not booting. Unplugging it and plugging it back in usually causes it to boot. Is there anything I can do in software? Like waiting a few seconds after connecting to power for booting or trying again after some time? Are there logs I can look at?

Comment: Is a UPS out of the question?

Comment: If there is any way to easily fix it in software I'd very much prefer that. If there is not I will probably have to look into that for this one and a few other devices.

Comment: This has presumably happened more than once.  What have you been doing to get the Pi booting again?

Comment: Unplugging it and plugging it back in again. Works most of the time. if not: repeat.

Comment: I am thinking of DIYing an UPS for my 12V LiPo Power Bank for Rpi.  I found the following discussion interesting.  Viability of using a USB power bank as a UPS? - rpi.org Forum 2018jun15
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=186091&sid=d1e64716b0bc1305c2c711cb962ed974  I might try it later,  if the long paragraphs are not boring me to death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi should boot when power is applied.

There is a hardware watchdog in the SOC which can be used to reboot of failure.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/68332/8697 (NOTE the bug mentioned is fixed in Stretch)

Comment: I set this up. So far it booted every time.