# After activating Watchdog on Raspbian the system goes to login screen when system reboots after freezing

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+, kiosk, watchdog, lightdm

I have made the necessary watchdog settings for **2021-12-02-raspios-buster-armhf** in accordance with [Watchdog on the RPi4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108080/watchdog-on-the-rpi4) in the operating system. When I test the watchdog with fork bomb command **sudo bash -c ':(){ :|:& };:'** the system reboots but goes to lightdm login screen where I need enter username and password.

In Raspbian I have created a user called kiosk and for autologin I have set config
**/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** and set the **autologin-user=kiosk**, by default it works okay but after Fork bomb autologin doesn't work.

I don't understand why autologin stops working in this kind of scenario, this can cause frustration for the user in a kiosk environment if the operating freezes.

Thanks

Comment: Does autologin fail every time you trigger the watchdog? Is there anything different in `lightdm.log`, compared to a successful autologin?

Comment: No, the autologin doesn't fail every time. in the log i can see WARNING: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files