# Hardware watchdog during reboot

Tags: raspbian, hardware, pi-3b+, reboot, watchdog

I'm creating a prototype of a Raspberry Pi 3B+ that uses Mender as the update manager. My goal is that if the Raspberry Pi is stuck somewhere in the boot process (Corrupted Kernel that cannot even panic) it will get reseted by the hardware watchdog after 10 seconds. But no matter how I configure the hardware watchdog, the Pi never reboots.

I've already read this thread cautiously : [How to keep watchdog timer running during reboot/shutdown](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68331/how-to-keep-watchdog-timer-running-during-reboot-shutdown)

I configured the Pi like in the post and I get this output:

```
Apr 27 17:57:18 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.818389] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting watchdog daemon...
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: starting daemon (5.15):
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: int=1s realtime=yes sync=no load=24,18,12 soft=no
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: memory not checked
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: ping: no machine to check
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: file: no file to check
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: pidfile: no server process to check
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: interface: no interface to check
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: temperature: no sensors to check
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: no test binary files
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: no repair binary files
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: error retry time-out = 60 seconds
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: repair attempts = 1
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: alive=/dev/watchdog heartbeat=[none] to=root no_act=no force=no
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: watchdog now set to 14 seconds
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi watchdog[458]: hardware watchdog identity: Broadcom BCM2835 Watchdog timer
Apr 27 17:57:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started watchdog daemon.
```

While the Pi seems to recognize that a hardware watchdog is present, it doesn't work.

Do you guys have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Quentin Rapin, welcome and nice to meet you. I followed #berto's tutorial to setup a watchdog, and everything goes well: 
"Rpi freezes every now and then, how to fix it with a watchdog?":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99584/rpi-freezes-every-now-and-then-how-to-fix-it. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this method does not work for me and my Pi is stuck on the rainbow screen...

Comment: Ah, sorry. I did not read your question too carefully.